# Remover todas as strings antes das chaves via javascript

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, scraping

Eu tenho um arquivo css e eu gostaria de gerar um JSON, pra isso, o primeiro passo que eu encontrei seria remover todo o seletor antes do colchetes

```
.meuSeletor {
  propriedade: valor;
}
```

para

```
{
  propriedade: valor;
}
```

Mas eu não tenho ideia de como fazer, não consegui pensar em nenhum regEx, nem um algoritmo pra selecionar e remover esse texto.

Como eu tenho todos os seletores em um arquivo, complica um pouco mais
Exemplo:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  background: #c1bdba;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1ab188;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Acho que não vai funcionar criar um JSON por causa dos valores das propriedades. Eles teriam que ficar entre aspas, senão vai dar erro. Por exemplo, isso `background: #c1bdba;` teria que ficar `background: "#c1bdba;"`.

Comment: Qual é a idea desse JSON? Podes explicar o problema que estás a tentar resolver?

Comment: Tenta [esse site](https://staxmanade.com/CssToReact/). Ou use essa [biblioteca](https://github.com/aramk/CSSJSON)